# Parsing a text file perl

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

A program, that is part of a pipeline, is parsing an output text file but raises an error. Here is the code

```
1 open(PRED, '<', $predfile);
2 my $pred_text;
3 { local $/; $pred_text = <PRED>; }
4 close PRED;

5 my @pred_blocks = split(/^\-+$/, $pred_text);

6  foreach my $pred_block (@pred_blocks) {
7     $pred_block =~ /^>(.+)$/m or die("Internal error while parsing $predfile");
   .....
}
```

What should contain $pred_text after line 3? I suppose the whole text file. I also suppose I should obtain different blocks from the text file, but the list in line 5 is containing only one block representing the whole file. What is the regex in line 5 doing? How it is splitting the text? And in line 7 what  $pred_block =~ /^>(.+)$/m exactly mean?

Any suggestion?

Many thanks

Nino

Answer (score 5):

- Line 3: reads the whole file, see [Perl Idioms Explained](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=287647)
- Line 5: *Doesn't* split the text into blocks. Change it to `my @pred_blocks = split(/^-+$/m, $pred_text);`, see [Modifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers)
- Line 7: checks, if the current block includes lines starting with `>`. If it doesn't, it aborts the script